# What's going on with vim-solarized's autoload/togglebg.vim script/keymapping?

Tags: vim

So I just installed [vim-colors-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) (using Pathogen), and discovered in the documentation that it features a script called `togglebg.vim` that maps `<F5>` to a function to toggle the background between light and dark – but I can't work out how to enable the mapping when vim starts up.

This script is located under `~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/autoload`. (I did [some reading](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/53.html) and think I understand how `autoload` folders work.) It contains the following function call, which maps `<F5>` as mentioned above:

```
if !exists("no_plugin_maps") && !hasmapto('<Plug>ToggleBackground')
    call togglebg#map("<F5>")
endif
```

Since it's in an `autoload` folder, vim does not source the script until something else (*e.g.,* `.vimrc`) calls one of its functions. Thus, the code above is not sufficient to invoke the keymapping, *because it is contained within the script itself*.

I know there are ways to source the script:

1. Renaming the script's parent directory from `autoload` to `plugin` will force vim to source it on startup.
2. Adding a line to `.vimrc` with a `call` to `togglebg#map()` will also force vim to autoload the script.

But none of this is mentioned in the documentation, which was most certainly written by people who understand vim way better than I do. All the documentation says is this:

> Solarized comes with Toggle Background, a simple plugin to switch between light and dark background modes and reset the colorscheme. This is most useful for colorschemes that support both light and dark modes and in terminals or gui vim windows where the background will be properly set.
>
> Toggle Background can be accessed by:
>
> ```
> ...
> * the default mapping of <F5>
> ...
> ```
>
> Toggle Background starts with a default mapping to function key `<F5>`. If you 
>   are already using this in a mapping, Toggle Background will not map itself to 
>   a default and you will have to map it manually in your .vimrc file, or 
>   remove/change your existing `<F5>` mapping to another value. To customize the 
>   keyboard mapping in your .vimrc file, use the following line, changing the 
>   `<F5>` value to the key or key combination you wish to use:
>
> ```
> call togglebg#map("<F5>")
> ```

That last line implies that I only need to `call togglebg#map()` *if* I want to map the `togglebg` function to a key other than `<F5>`, and that the `<F5>` keybinding should be available on installation without any further mussing and fussing.

So what am I missing here? Is there a "proper" way to source this script and enable the 'default' `<F5>` mapping? Could it be that somebody moves the files around in the repo and forgot to update the documentation, or vice versa? Or am I supposed to suck it up and just make a function call from `.vimrc`?

#### EDIT

It's working all of a sudden. I don't know what I changed in my `.vimrc` file, if anything, but it definitely wasn't working at work yesterday (gVim on Windows), and it's definitely working at home now (also gVim on Windows, `vimfiles` folder synced via Dropbox).

But maybe I can amend this question: If this functionality is supposed to be available by default, why is the script placed in an `autoload` folder?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this is a mistake and the documentation is not precise. [Relevant issue](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/40) and [pull-req closed before being merged](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/pull/43)

Comment: Yeah, looks like an acknowledged bug in the plugin. And from the looks of it, I'd guess the OP was wrong, and actually DOES know more about how autoload works than the plugin author. ;-)